# Traversal order in java collections

Tags: java, collections

In which of the Collections in java is traversal order predictable?
I want to know where I can get predictable order output when i print the elements inside a loop.

Comment: [java.util.list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) are ordered collections , meaning that the elements of the collection have a specific order. The order is independent of the value.

Comment: Just read the javadoc... -1 for lack of research

Answer (score 0):

The [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface and its implementations are ordered collections.

```
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            list.add(i);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.print(list.get(i)+" ");
        }
```

Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

This shows that the list followed insertion order.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil,Varun,nivox for your comments. :)

Comment: please choose a correct answer for future references to other SO users. You can also up vote useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

The List implementations or any of the SortedMap, SortedSet implementations are predictable.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really general: what kind of collection are you interested in? Lists, sets, queues?

In general you can expect any implementation of List to have a predictable traversal order.
Generic sets instead do not provide any guarantees in the order of the traversal, however SortedSet subclasses (TreeSet) do provide predictable traversal ordering.

I strongly suggest you to check the javadoc for java.util.Collection and check the various subinterfaces untill you find a collection that provides predictable traversal ordering (this is usually clearly specified in the javadoc. See List, SortedSet, etc) and fit your problem.